# Why does JsonConvert change time of DateTimes with DateTimeKind.Unspecified when using DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal?

Tags: datetime, json.net

I'm building a web API and am having trouble with the JSON serialization of `DateTimes`. After doing some tests I can only conclude that the behavior of `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` and/or the Newtonsoft `IsoDateTimeConverter` is not what I expected.

Consider this:

```
// Arrange
var noonUtc = new DateTime(2016, 05, 12, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var noon = new DateTime(2016, 05, 12, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter
{    
    Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,    
    DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
});

// Act
var utcJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(noonUtc, settings); // "\"2016-05-12T12:00:00Z\""
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(noon, settings);       // "\"2016-05-12T10:00:00Z\""

... // Assertions
```

Okay, so the time for the `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` has been adjusted from 12 o'clock to 10 o'clock. I'm in Stockholm which is currently two hours ahead of UTC, so fair enough.

However, let's change the serializer settings to use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`, like so:

```
settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter
{    
    Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,    
    DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal
});
```

This results in the *exact* same strings and thus also adjusts the `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` by two hours! Should it not assume the date time was already UTC time and leave the time as it was? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything; this looks like it might be a bug in the `IsoDateTimeConverter`.  Here is the relevant code from the [source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs#L88):

```
if ((_dateTimeStyles & DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal) == DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
   || (_dateTimeStyles & DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal) == DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)
{
    dateTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
}
```

As you can see, it only looks at whether `_dateTimeStyles` is set to `AdjustToUniversal` or `AssumeUniversal` before calling `ToUniversalTime()`; it never checks the date's `Kind` property.

And the documentation for `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` says this:

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, the value returned by the `ToUniversalTime` method is determined by the `Kind` property of the current `DateTime` object. The following table describes the possible results.
>
> ```
> Kind        | Results
> ----------- | ----------------------------------------------------------
> Utc         | No conversion is performed.
> Local       | The current DateTime object is converted to UTC.
> Unspecified | The current DateTime object is assumed to be a local time, 
>             | and the conversion is performed as if Kind were Local.
> ```

So yeah, it looks like the converter should definitely not be calling `ToUniversalTime` in this situation. You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues).

For now, you can work around this issue by implementing a replacement converter (derived from the original) with the correct behavior.  This is probably closer to what you would want:

```
public class CorrectedIsoDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    private const string DefaultDateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK";

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)value;

            if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
            {
                if (DateTimeStyles.HasFlag(DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal))
                {
                    dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }
                else if (DateTimeStyles.HasFlag(DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal))
                {
                    dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Local);
                }
            }

            if (DateTimeStyles.HasFlag(DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal))
            {
                dateTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
            }

            string format = string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateTimeFormat) ? DefaultDateTimeFormat : DateTimeFormat;
            writer.WriteValue(dateTime.ToString(format, Culture));
        }
        else
        {
            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }
    }
}
```